# Translating a Python Pandas line to R:

Tags: python, r, pandas

I am following a blog post [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/financial-machine-learning-part-0-bars-745897d4e4ba) and I am getting a little stuck on one part regarding the translation from Python pandas to R…

In the part of the blog:

## Tick Bars

The author has the line:

`data_tick_grp = data.reset_index().assign(grpId=lambda row: row.index // num_ticks_per_bar)`

- I understand that `data` is the "data frame" -
- `reset_index` not sure what this is.
- `assing(grpId =…)` - creating a new variable `grpId`
- `lambda row:` - not sure what this does.
- `row.index` - is this the same as `row_number`?
- `\\` - is this the same as `floor()` in R?
- `num_ticks_per_bar` is calculated as.

  `total_ticks = len(data)
  num_ticks_per_bar = total_ticks / num_time_bars
  num_ticks_per_bar = round(num_ticks_per_bar, -3) # round to the nearest thousand`

Which I understand it as:

```
ticks <- data %>%
  filter(symbol == "XBTUSD") %>%
  nrow()
ticks_per_bar <- ticks / 288
ticks_per_bar <- plyr::round_any(ticks_per_bar, 1000)
floor(1:nrow(data) / ticks_per_bar))
```

Can somebody help me translate the Python pandas line into R language?

Comment: For reset.index() see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html
Basically it resets the dataframe after the groupby which happens a paragraph above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, Pandas best translates to base R:

- `reset_index` same as resetting `row.names` for sequential numbering `data.frame(..., row.names = NULL)`
- `assign(grpId =…)` same as assigning a column in place such as with `transform`, `within` or dplyr's `mutate`
- `lambda row` this is required inside `assign` to reference data frame, here aliased as *row*
- `row.index` is same as row number (remember Python is 0-index unlike R)
- `//` is the integer division which in R one can be wrapped with `as.integer` or `floor` after division

Altogether, consider below adjustment to translate Pandas line:

```py
data_tick_grp = (data.reset_index()
                     .assign(grpId=lambda row: row.index // num_ticks_per_bar)
                )
```

To R:

```r
data_tick_grp <- transform(data.frame(data, row.names = NULL),
                           grpId = floor(0:(nrow(data)-1) / num_ticks_per_bar))
```

Or in tidy format:

```
data_tick_grp <- data %>%
                   data.frame(row.names = NULL) %>%
                   mutate(grpId = floor(0:(nrow(data)-1) / num_ticks_per_bar))
```

Comment: Thanks this is awesome! I get somewhat similar answer to the author. I have just one more "similar" question: A little further I come across the line `data_vol_grp = data_cm_vol.assign(grpId=lambda row: row.cmVol // vol_per_bar)` in the "Volume Bars" section. Is this the same as in R: `mutate(Volcumsum = cumsum(homeNotional),
         grp = floor(Volcumsum) / vol_per_bar) %>%
  group_by(grp)`

Comment: Sounds good. Glad to help. Yes that is a correct translation as again *row* in [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) is the data frame reference, so `row.cmVol` or `row['cmVol]` refers to entire *cmVol* column in data frame. Using *row* alias may be misleading by author as no rowwise loop is run here.